# Output shape of layer custom by keras

Tags: python, keras

I want create a layer Linear like y = w*x+b, with w is matrix[Mxd], x is matrix[dx1], b is bias as matrix[Mx1], with M is the units in a layer, d is dim of vector x.
my code like:

```
class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, units=32):
    super(Linear, self).__init__()
    self.units = units
    print(self.units)

def build(self, input_shape):
    
    self.w = self.add_weight(
        shape=( self.units, input_shape[1]),
        initializer="random_normal",
        trainable=True,
    )
    self.b = self.add_weight(
        shape=(self.units,1), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
    )
    print(input_shape[1])

def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.matmul(self.w, inputs) + self.b

def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
    return (self.units, 1)
```

And when i create model i use:

```
    input_tensor1 = Input((2,1))
    L11 = Linear(32)(input_tensor1)

    model = Model(inputs=input_tensor1, outputs=L11)
    model.summary()
```

In this code d=2 and M=32
As i think y =w*x+b, y will be a matrix[Mx1] cause w is [Mxd], x is [dx1] and b is [Mx1]. But when model summary, output_shape is (None, 2, 1)

Can anyone explain it? where my code wrong?

Comment: I did run your code, It is giving me the output shape (None, 32, 1). Check you indentation . The four function you defined should be in class.

Comment: yes, all 4 function in class, i run model.summary() and it return me output_shape is (None, 2, 1)

Comment: Make sure all the imports either from tensorflow.keras or keras

Comment: all import from keras except the function tf.matmul()

Comment: try imports from tensorflow.keras instead

Comment: oh, it's work, u right bro. Thank so much, but why keras is bug? need change all to tensorflow.keras?

Comment: I imported eveything from keras except tf.matmul(), It still works for me. I suggest you to update your keras(2.4.3) and tensorflow(2.2.0) upto the latest version. I'm guessing problem is with your keras which is not updated

Comment: i using google colab

Comment: and 1 more question tf.matmul() is multiple 2 tensor (matrix) and what diffirence with K.dot(). I see in the doc they use K.dot for Keras code

Comment: colab is using older version of keras(2.3.1). Two operations are similar except that the default dtype they uses. And i suggest you to use only one module tf.keras or keras otherwise it will ofetnly creates problem while using both

Comment: Ok i noted it. Thank you again for answering me so fast!